# asp.net updatepanel and firefox Page.IsValid causes exception

Tags: asp.net, firefox

I have the following asp.net code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {$(".button").click(function (event) {
        alert("Button pressed!");
    });
});
</script>
<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" CssClass="button" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="testUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="testTextBox" EventName="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="testTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="test" CssClass="Test" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="testRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="testTextBox" ErrorMessage="*2" ValidationExpression="(19|20)\d\d\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-([012][0-9]|3[01])" ValidationGroup="test" />
        <asp:Label ID="testLabel" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the following codebehind:

```
Private Sub testTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles testTextBox.TextChanged
    If (Not Page.IsValid) Then
        Return
    End If
    testLabel.Text = testTextBox.Text
End Sub
```

If i run this in FF(v15,v15.0.1) type 1987-05-03 in the textbox and then press enter, it triggers the button, after that i get a postback to testTextBox_TextChanged, and when it hits he line `If (Not Page.IsValid)` Then i get the following exception:

```
Page.IsValid cannot be called before validation has taken place. It should be queried in the event handler for a control that has CausesValidation=True and initiated the postback, or after a call to Page.Validate.
```

If i do the same in IE the button is never triggerd, and i get no exception!
So why does FF misbehave like this? i have not set a DefaultButton on any of my panels..

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
Page.Validate("test")
```

before that line and it will be guaranteed validated in all scenarios.  It could still be happening in IE, but the error is swallowed somehow...

Comment: Yes this makes the exception go away but it does not solve the real problem, the button should never be triggerd...

Answer (score 0):

Add the `CausesValidation` property to `true` to your `TextBox`

Or, call `this.Validate` before checking the `IsValid` property

The above will remove the exception, however the incompatibility with IE and FF will remain

Comment: If you look at my asp.net you will see that CausesValidation is set to true on the textbox..